# A simple identity for Thetaseries

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, theta-functions

Let $\vartheta(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2z}$ be a thetafunction. I want to show that $\vartheta(z)+\vartheta(z+1)=2\vartheta(4z)$.

After using the definition I only get to this point:

$\vartheta(z)+\vartheta(z+1)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2z}+e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2z}*e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2z}(1+(-1)^n)$. Can somebody help me with the last step. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean [$\vartheta(z)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i} n^2 z}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function) and $$\vartheta(z)+\vartheta(z+1)= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2 z}(1+e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2 }) =\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2 z}(1+(-1)^{n^2})$$
$$ =  2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z},n \text{ even}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2  z} =  2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}(2n)^2  z}=2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi\mathrm{i}n^2 4 z}=2 \vartheta(4z)$$

Comment: Oh, yes of course, I just edited it. I don't know how I just made the same mistake over and over again. Thank you for the answer :)